# Does dictionary contain key containing multiple partial strings?

Tags: python

I'm trying to test a dictionary to see if it contains keys that contain partial strings. Specifically, I am building a wing generator which assigns each feather's control to a dictionary. On a button click to mirror the wing, I need to test if the wing had already been mirrored (and then if it has subsequently been undone/deleted, but that's not part of this question and is easily tested for). I wish to do this by checking the feather dictionary to see if it has Keys containing both "L_" as well as "R_".

The following code does what I want, but is rather verbose. There has got to be a simpler, more elegant way to do it:

```
dict={}
RS=False
LS=False
for each in dict:
    if "L_" in each:
        LS=True
    if "R_" in dict:
        LS=True
if LS and RS:
    print "has both"
```

alternatively, would it just be simpler to create another global variable and store a mirrored true/false value into that to test for? I'm trying to keep my global variables to a minimum, but am uncertain on how they influence resources. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that code does what you want? I think you mean `if "R_" in each:`, and you repeat `LS=True` instead of `RS=True`. Also, do you mean to have `if LS and RS:` inside the loop? If so, don't you need to reset LS and RS to False each iteration? If you make your code work, the people here can more easily show you a way to make your code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is less verbose, has the opportunity to break the search early when matching keys are found, but still makes two complete passes over the keys in the worst case.

```
if any('L_' in key for key in dict) and any('R_' in key for key in dict):
    print 'has both'
```

Note: it's a little ambiguous in your question if you are looking for `L_` and `R_` to appear in the *same* key or not (for example: `"...L_...R_..."`). If that is the case, use:

```
if any('L_' in key and 'R_' in key for key in dict):
    print 'has both'
```

This way is more verbose, but breaks out as soon as possible, and only makes one pass even in the worst case.

```
RS=False
LS=False
for each in dict:
    if "L_" in each:
        LS=True
    if "R_" in dict:
        RS=True
    if LS and RS:
        print 'has both'
        break
```

Which you use I suppose depends on if you need to make optimizations if you have many keys in your dictionary, and only making one pass in the worst case would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It appears I wasn't to far off from the second option, but the less verbose method is good to know as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the dictionary in the first place, have two different dictionaries. Put the values in the right dictionary (which might be both, based on your description). In fact, have a both dictionary.

Then this search problem will not occur.

Comment: I create the feathers (the number of feathers is variable) using a separate method which creates each feather individually, then assign the control name to a dictionary. When I mirror, I run that same method with it's # of feathers value based on the length of the opposite sides dictionary (it then runs through each control of the new side and copies the attributes from the feather control on the opposite side). Because it's the same method creating both sides, it uses the same dictionary. So I'm not sure a second feather dictionary is practical, or better than a "mirror test" global variable.

Comment: @Kratch This really sounds like you shouldn't be separating the sides if that is the case. I find your descriptions too obscure to recommend more suitable data structures, but I'm sure that there are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a more functional style you can build a function which classifies feathers according to your classes:

```
def classify(s):
    return set(['L']) if 'L_' in s else set(['R'])
```

Then just apply a reduce to your keys:

```
wing = {'L_feather': 6 , 'R_feather' : 5}
reduce(lambda x, y: classify(x) | classify(y), wing)
```

Results in a set containing both whit you can easily check with len() of .issubset() or whatever:

```
Out[30]:
set(['R', 'L'])
```

This should transverse your list only once.